# CircleObject is not abstract and does not override abstract method in figure

Tags: java

When compiling the code below, I get the following error:

```
Abstrct.java:7: error: CircleObject is not abstract and does not override abstract method changePosition(int,int) in Figure
class CircleObject extends Figure
^
Abstrct.java:14: error: Kd is not abstract and does not override abstract method draw() in Figure
class Kd extends Figure
^
2 errors
```

Using

```
abstract class Figure {

    int x, y;

    abstract void changePosition(int newX, int newY);

    abstract void draw();
}

class CircleObject extends Figure {

    void draw() {
        System.out.println("Draw method called");
    }
}

class Kd extends Figure {

    void changePosition(int newX, int newY) {
        System.out.println("Change Position method called");
    }
}

class Abstrct {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Figure q = new CircleObject();
        q.draw();
        Figure p = new Kd();
        p.changePosition(2, 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Circle` either needs to be `abstract` or implement the `changePosition` method

Answer (score 0):

A class extending an abstract class has either to implement all the abstract methods of its parent class, or be abstract itself.

So your CircleObject class has to implement changePosition() too, or be an abstract class itself.

Similar for the Kd class.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a class as abstract,  all classes extending it need to implement ALL methods.

```
abstract class Figure {
    int x, y;
    abstract void changePosition(int newX, int newY);
    abstract void draw();
}

class CircleObject extends Figure {
    void draw() {
        System.out.println("Draw method called");
    }
    void changePosition(int newX, int newY){        
    }
}

class Kd extends Figure {
    void changePosition(int newX, int newY) {
        System.out.println("Change Position method called");
    }
    void draw(){        
    }
}
```